# why TextToSpeech synthesizeToFile returns -1?

Tags: java, android, file, debugging, text-to-speech

I'm trying to create a file with synthesizeToFile:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this, "com.google.android.tts");

public void onInit(int status)
{
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
        String textToGenerate = "this is a test";
        // /data/data/com.domain.my/files is returned by getFilesDir()
        String completePathFile = "/data/data/com.domain.my/files/_12345_test";

        File fileToGenerate = new File(completePathFile);
        String fileName = fileToGenerate.getName();

        // this works on Android 6
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            Bundle bundleTts = new Bundle();
            bundleTts.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, fileName);

            tts.synthesizeToFile
            (
                    textToGenerate
                    , bundleTts
                    , fileToGenerate
                    , fileName
            );
        }
        // this doesn't works on Android 4.1: response is -1
        else
        {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, fileName);

            int response = tts.synthesizeToFile
            (
                    textToGenerate
                    , hashMap
                    , completePathFile
            );
            Log.d("testTTS", "Generation file " + fileName + " - response = " + response);
        }
    }
}
```

With the device having Android 6 the `synthesizeToFile` method works fine.

With the device having Android 4.1 the `synthesizeToFile` method returns `-1`.

I already checked with getEngines() that "com.google.android.tts" is installed.

How can I debug my script to discover why `synthesizeToFile` returns `-1`?

There is an alternative way to generate that file with TTS?

I need to do that in the internal storage (the Path returned by `getFilesDir()`) so I must not ask for external storage permission.

**EDIT:**

In the logcat I found this error:

```
E/TextToSpeechService: Can't use /data/data/com.domain.my/files/_12345_test due to exception java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I already tried:

```
setWritable(true)
```

and

```
setWritable(true, true)
```

But even if both return `true`, the Exception still occurs.

So, now how to solve this?

Comment: Don't know this API. Does it also set errno? Is there any "last error" method in the TextToSpeech class?

Comment: @GemTaylor I searched in the whole documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) but unfortunately there isn't such method :(

Comment: Probably still worth checking the global errno

Comment: I don't know the TTS API at all, but if I look at the doc you just linked in the comment above I see the following mentioned at the [`synthesizeToFile` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)): "_In order to reliably detect errors during synthesis, we recommend setting an utterance progress listener (see `setOnUtteranceProgressListener(UtteranceProgressListener)`) and using the `Engine#KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID` parameter._" Not sure if that helps somehow?

Comment: @GemTaylor can you please tell me the exact method and class to get that or a documentation link? Thanks

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, I seen that note but the `synthesizeToFile` method returns a value that represent the result of the action "put the request in the queue" and then do that in async. If that action to queue fails, it return false without attempt to synthese. In the documentation: return "ERROR (-1) or SUCCESS (0) of queuing the synthesizeToFile operation"

Comment: For reference errno: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

Comment: @user2342558 Ah ok. I had indeed seen that the `-1` it returns is due to the `ERROR`. I don't know the API, but I take your word on it that when an `ERROR`/`-1` is returned, the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener(UtteranceProgressListener)` isn't useful because it doesn't attempt to synthesize yet. Kinda makes sense, but still a bit of a counter-intuitive note in that case due to "_In order to reliably detect **errors**_", but I guess the emphasized part is "_to reliably detect errors **during synthesis**_". Sorry I couldn't help any further.

Comment: I would suggest testing whether the older implementation (contained with your else {} clause) works on recent APIs.  If not, then the problem is in that code.  You can also use your logcat to see more detail about why the -1 is returned, such as read only file system on a simulator, etc.  Also... I noticed that your params for synthesizeToFile are different for the older implementation (completeFilePath vs fileName).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that to know the reason of the value `-1` returned by `synthesizeToFile` I need to see in the logcat:

> E/TextToSpeechService: Can't use /data/data/com.domain.my/files/_12345_test due to exception java.io.IOException: open failed: **EACCES (Permission denied)**

Now, I must know why this exception occurs...

Comment: can you post solution because synthesize stopping me to create a file why error -1 pls help me herre android pie

Comment: using path is ---   /storage/emulated/0/RingTone/HEY.mp3 failed